# How to switch order of last name and first name and remove coma

Tags: python-3.x

Might be a simple question but I am very new to Python.

If I have a given "Last Name, First Name", how would I switch the order to "First Name Last Name''?

For example, if I have:

`"Doe, John"`

How would I make it

`"John Doe"`?

I tried using `.split()`, but that converts it into a List and I want it to be a string.

EDIT: The suggested question gives a List, however my example is just a string

This is the code that I came up with:

```
def change_name(name: str) -> str:
    x = name.split(',')
    x.reverse()
    x.join()
```

but that just gives me an error that the list doesn't have the attribute join

Also, I did `str(x).join(' ')` but that just gives me the List `['John', 'Doe']`

EDIT: I seem to have gotten closer to what I want but it's still not perfect.
Now I have :

```
def change_name(name: str) -> str:
    x = name.split(',')
    x.reverse()
    separator = ','
    return separator.join(x)
```

which gives me

`' John,Doe'`

Now the problem is I need to take out the space in front of the string and the comma.

Comment: You are on the right track. First `split` it into a list, `reverse` it, then `join` to make it a string again.

Comment: _What_ tells you that? Post your modified code, or read the docs for `str.join()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is to use a comma to join the First Name and Last Name while you should have used a space. Try this:

```
>>> name = "Doe, John"
>>> x = name.split(', ')
>>> x.reverse()
>>> separator = ' '
>>> separator.join(x)
'John Doe'
```

The operations can also be chained in a single line, such as

```
>>> ' '.join(reversed(name.split(', ')))
'John Doe'
```